# Tree diagram has lopsided branch

Tags: forest, linguistics, trees

I'm attempting to draw a tree diagram using the `forest` package that shows the morphological derivation of a word. However, when I align the terminal nodes, the highest branch looks lopsided. This is what I have:

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{forest}
  [Adj
    [un, tier=morph]
    [Adj
      [lock, tier=morph]
      [able, tier=morph]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

This produces the following:

[image: Lopsided tree diagram]

How might I increase the height of the top node or set it further to the right so that all the branches split at the same angle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask for `fixed angles` or `fixed edge angles`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed angles}
  [Adj
    [un, tier=morph]
    [Adj
      [lock, tier=morph]
      [able, tier=morph]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}
  [Adj
    [un, tier=morph]
    [Adj
      [lock, tier=morph]
      [able, tier=morph]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not a linguist, just a marmot, and I would do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed angles,parent anchor=south}
  [Adj
    [un, tier=morph]
    [Adj
      [lock, tier=morph]
      [able, tier=morph]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles,parent anchor=south}
  [Adj
    [un, tier=morph]
    [Adj
      [lock, tier=morph]
      [able, tier=morph]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]